# migratordotnet - Run migrations from within application (w/o nant or build)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, migrator.net

is there a way to run migrations from within the application itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I instantiate an instance of the Migrator class, and then you can call member methods like `MigrateToLastVersion()` or `MigrateTo(long versionnr)`

```
Migrator.Migrator m = new Migrator.Migrator ("SqlServer", connectionString, migrationsAssembly)

m.MigrateToLastVersion();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it...

I made a class-projekt and did everything like in the tutorials.
Then i made a new web-project and included the migration.dll and my compiled assembly.

Then I included your source-code, but where can I find the right migration-assembly? It only finds my namespace "DBMigration", but there comes an error message "DBMigration is a namespace, but its used as a type". Can you help me?

Comment: Solved it... With System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(...)

Comment: That's indeed how it should be done. :)  Load the assembly file that contains your migrations into an Assembly instance, and pass it to the Migrator class. :)

Comment: Get your assembly like this: var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Migration_0001));

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

Have a look at the nant task http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/source/browse/trunk/src/Migrator.NAnt/MigrateTask.cs

Relevant bits are here:

```
    private void Execute(Assembly asm)
    {
        Migrator mig = new Migrator(Provider, ConnectionString, asm, Trace, new TaskLogger(this));
        mig.DryRun = DryRun;
        if (ScriptChanges)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ScriptFile))
            {
                mig.Logger = new SqlScriptFileLogger(mig.Logger, writer);
                RunMigration(mig);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RunMigration(mig);
        }
    }

    private void RunMigration(Migrator mig)
    {
        if (mig.DryRun)
            mig.Logger.Log("********** Dry run! Not actually applying changes. **********");

        if (_to == -1)
            mig.MigrateToLastVersion();
        else
            mig.MigrateTo(_to);
    }
```