# How do you tell if your migrations are up to date with migratordotnet?

Tags: .net, sql-server, migration, migratordotnet

I'm using [migratordotnet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) to manage my database migrations.  I'm [running them on application setup like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868223/migratordotnet-run-migrations-from-within-application-w-o-nant-or-build), but I would also like to check on application startup that the migrations are up to date, and provide the option to migrate to latest.  How do I tell if there are available migrations that need to be applied?  I see that I can get the migrations that were applied like this

```
var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Migration_0001));
var migrator = new Migrator.Migrator("SqlServer", setupInfo.DatabaseConnectionString, asm);
var applied = migrator.AppliedMigrations;
```

I like to do something like this:

```
var available = migrator.AvailableMigrations; //this property does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way.  Looking at migratordotnet source code helps.

```
var provider = ProviderFactory.Create("SqlServer", myConnectionString);
var loader = new MigrationLoader(provider, asm, false);
var availableMigrations = loader.GetAvailableMigrations();
```